# Laravel 5.4 Upgrade -- Integrity constraint violation - Column cannot be null

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.4

The strange thing is -- all of this was working at 5.2, but I don't know what could have changed to make this happen. Below is the error and the array being inserted.

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'gender' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `tenants` (`name`, `phone`, `email`, `description`, `gender`, `date_birth`, `background_check_status`, `picture_url`, `work`, `position`, `country`, `location`, `hobbies`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Amadeo Levy Luna, 18065496549, amadeo.luna@ttu.edu, , , 2017-05-08 20:29:50, 0, , , , , , , 2017-05-08 20:29:50, 2017-05-08 20:29:50)) ◀"
array:13 [▼
  "_token" => "9HeacY4KskT5vpLPGCUTkzVxRcpcKMNjdob79aLs"
  "name" => "Amadeo Levy Luna"
  "phone" => "18065496549"
  "email" => "amadeo.luna@ttu.edu"
  "description" => null
  "gender" => null
  "background_check_status" => "0"
  "picture_url" => null
  "work" => null
  "position" => null
  "country" => null
  "location" => null
  "hobbies" => null
]
```

This is breaking in many different fields all over the website, but none of them broke before. What changed in Laravel to create this?

Comment: Ensure that the gender column is nullable in the database.

Comment: any migration files..? we want to take a peek.. also, can you check on the table.. whether it allows null or not.. Laravel should not introduce such breaking code.. since saving things handled by db.. Laravel only pass it to db..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming nothing changed in your code the only thing I could think of is the two new middleware introduced in 5.4: `TrimStrings` and `ConvertEmptyStringsToNull`.

Try comment the latter or both in `app\Http\Kernel.php`

```php
class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    protected $middleware = [
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        // \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
    ];

    // ...
}
```

Comment: `ConvertEmptyStringsToNull` would likely seem to be the culprit. The first strings were passing '' to the database, and now they're trying to pass `NULL`.

Comment: You're a life save, literally been spending hours as it was a giant run-around figuring out various aspects. Thank you.

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 2):

Continuing on @peterm's anwser.

If you still want to convert empty strings to `null` (for other parts of your application) and don't want to uncomment `\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class`, you have two options.

1. Add `nullable` to your column in the database.
2. Use [events](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#events) such as `saving` on your model to add a default value to your property if it is `null`.

Here is an example on how to add `nullable` to your columns (if you've already created the table and if you're using mysql):

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class AddNullToColumns extends Migration {
    public function __construct() {
        $this->charset = config('database.connections.mysql.charset');
        $this->collate = config('database.connections.mysql.collation');
    }
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up() {
        // Change multiple columns on a table.
        DB::statement("ALTER TABLE `" . (new \App\User)->getTable() . "`
            CHANGE `phone` `phone` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET {$this->charset} COLLATE {$this->collate} NULL DEFAULT NULL,
            CHANGE `address` `address` TEXT CHARACTER SET {$this->charset} COLLATE {$this->collate} NULL DEFAULT NULL,
            CHANGE `comment` `comment` TEXT CHARACTER SET {$this->charset} COLLATE {$this->collate} NULL DEFAULT NULL;");

        // Change one column on a table.
        DB::statement("ALTER TABLE `" . (new \App\Report)->getTable() . "` CHANGE `comment` `comment` TEXT CHARACTER SET {$this->charset}COLLATE {$this->collate}NULL DEFAULT NULL");
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down() {
        DB::statement("ALTER TABLE `" . (new \App\User)->getTable() . "`
            CHANGE `phone` `phone` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET {$this->charset} COLLATE {$this->collate} NOT NULL,
            CHANGE `address` `address` TEXT CHARACTER SET {$this->charset} COLLATE {$this->collate} NOT NULL,
            CHANGE `comment` `comment` TEXT CHARACTER SET {$this->charset} COLLATE {$this->collate} NOT NULL;");

        DB::statement("ALTER TABLE `" . (new \App\Report)->getTable() . "` CHANGE `comment` `comment` TEXT CHARACTER SET {$this->charset}COLLATE {$this->collate}NOT NULL");
    }
}
```

Here is an example on how to use events:

```
<?php

namespace App;

class User extends Authenticatable {
    public static function boot() {
        // When creating or updated the model.
        static::saving(function($model){
            // Use value of gender if available, if `null` use `unisex`.
            $model->gender = $model->gender ?: 'unisex';
        });
    }
}
```