# PHP - Skip default false when setting NULL

Tags: php, null

I wrote some code that sets all fields to NULL in my Symfony project. But when I set one of the fields to

```
 private $processed = false;
```

It throws:

> Integrity constraint violation: Column 'processed' cannot be null

How can I skip that and loop all results.

```
  public function fill($fields, $mainEnitity)
{
    foreach($fields as $field) {

        $setter = 'set' . ucfirst($field);

        if ($field == false){
            continue;
        }

        if (method_exists($mainEnitity, $setter)) {

            $originalValue = NULL;

            $mainEnitity->$setter($originalValue);
        }
    }
```

NOTE: When I remove 'false field' my code works. I just want to work with logic where I can skip false fileds and set all other filds to null.

Comment: Perhaps check for `$field === false`.

Comment: `$setter = 'set' . ucfirst($field);` you should instead look into using the magicmethod `__set()` - https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.set

Comment: you may find interesting this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43860634/laravel-5-4-upgrade-integrity-constraint-violation-column-cannot-be-null

Comment: You always set `$originalValue` null. Some columns, like `processed`, can't be null.

Comment: Tried. Doesn't work. @ryantxr

Comment: I will look into it! @Qirel

Comment: I don't want to set it to NULL. I want to skip fields that are set to false so it doesn't throw an error. @Qirel

Comment: But you are *explicitly* setting it to NULL. You are never using a condition on it. `$originalValue = NULL;` never changes. Its only when the `$field` variable (which holds the name of the setter) that you skip the iteration. When you set a value, you ALWAYS set it to null.